# AnyLogic: SelectOutput Condition Color

Tags: anylogic

I want agents with the FillColor blue to take the "true" exit at a selectOutout block. I can't get the "If condition is true" condition to work.

Already tried with parameters, variables and different quotes but can't get it right.
Can someone please help?

Answer (score 0):

Agents do not have a color. Animation elements within an agent have colors.

If you have a rectangle `myRectangle` with color blue in your agent and the agent flows through the SelectOutput, you can use `agent.myRectangle.getColor.equals(Color.blue)`

Comment: Thanks, this might go in the right direction. AnyLogic now gives me the error: "Cannot make a static reference to the non-static field agent.myRectangle." (In my case Box.rectangle") The error occurs in the SelectOutput condition.


Is my agent non-static because the animation element "rectangle" within my agent "Box" has a random color?
On startup, my agent gets the command: "rectangle.setFillColor(randomFrom(Colors));


Can we solve this?

Comment: no, search here for this error, tons of people had the same issue before. It has to do with OOP basics and Java, not AnyLogic